# Remove similar records when iterating an ActiveRecord relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I would like to find the best way to remove items from an array during an iteration of ActiveRecord results.

I want to remove the record from the array, not from the database. So I can't use *a.delete(record)* for example.

```
# find similar items @items in a AR relation array
@items = Item.where("toto = ?", value).to_a
@items.each do |i|

  # match similar records using postgres
  @similar_items = ...

  # now try to remove similar items from original @items array
  @similar_items.each do |similar_item|

    # this seems to not work
    @items.reject! { |item_to_remove| 
      item_to_remove == similar_item
    end 

  end

end
```

In fact, my goal is to remove all duplicates from the array using similar items matched to not reiterate them.

Comment: Do you mean literally equivalent or is there some kind of "similarity" function you're running?

Comment: I'm using the similarity (Ngrams) feature from Postgres.

Comment: Here you're doing a straight `==` comparison, so it's hard to say how this would ever work.

Comment: Even using the id of the record: `wine_to_remove.id == similar_wine.id`, it seems to not work.

Comment: This may be something you need to do entirely in the database using the similarity function. Ruby might not be equipped with the tools.

Comment: I used Postgres but once I have found similar items, I need to remove them from the loop else the next occurence will match them too.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you the following approach:

1. Collect all similar items
2. Return collection where you have excluded these similar items.

It should simplify your code and make fewer iterations.

```
    @items = Item.where("toto = ?", value).to_a

    similar_items = @items.reduce([]) do |r, i|
      @similar_items = ...
      (r + @similar_items).flatten
    end

    filtered_collection = @items.reject { |item| similar_items.include?(item) }
```

Comment: I don't understand the line` r + @similar_items`. Missing something ? (no implicit conversion of nil into Array)

Comment: Added small fix. The general idea is to build an array of _all_ possible similar items for _all_ elements of original array